# How to use C# function in Java using JNA lib

Tags: c#, java, dll, jna

I've spent many hours trying to use a C# function inside my Java Application but had no success...
I wrote the following lib in C#:

```
public class Converter
{

    public Converter()
    {
    }

    public bool ConvertHtmlToPdf(String directoryPath)
    {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

This dll calls another dll to make some operations but when I compile it I can find Dlls in my Realse folder and everything seems to be ok, so I compiled it using 32bit option, 64bit, and Any CPU option just to make sure that it's not my issue.

Analizing my dll files with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) in 32 bit and Any CPU option it says that IESHIMS.DLL can't be found, and show this message:

Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

It doesn't occur with the 64bit file, nevertheless I can't find my ConvertHtmlToPdf function.

As I don't know if it is relevant or not, my second step was in the Java Code.

To load my library I do:

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Facilit\\Target App\\lib");
```

and:

```
public interface IConversorLibrary extends Library {

    IConversorLibrary INSTANCE = (IConversorLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("converter", IConversorLibrary.class);

    void ConvertHtmlToPdf(String directoryPath);
}
```

(The lib seems to be load successful, cause if I try to delete dll file with my application running it says that can't be deleted cause it's in using)
and finally:

```
IConversorLibrary.INSTANCE.ConvertHtmlToPdf(directoryPath);
```

But the result is not really as I wish:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'ConvertHtmlToPdf': Could not find the specified procedure.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've tried many tutorials and many things, but anything seems to work, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Setting `jna.library.path` is not really going to affect JNA; you would need to set `%PATH%` instead.  The latter actually affects shared library loading, which `jna.library.path` does not.

Comment: If you don't see your function name listed in dependency walker, JNA certainly won't be able to find it.

Comment: JNA can load from DLLs that use C linkage.  A C# class does not by default support any kind of C linkage.  C++ supports C linkage with the `extern "C"` notation.

Comment: @technomage Is there a way make it "findable" to JNA? Some tutorial, or just an idea?

Comment: [This article](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Do-you-know-a-tool-to-automate-making-C-DLLs-exports-callable-from-native-code) suggests you might be able to hack the C# DLL loading to do what you want.

Comment: Be sure to use the 64-bit depends with 64-bit DLLs; similarly for 32-bit. The docs do discuss that there are optional dependencies that will be marked missing and that you can ignore them. As @technomage says, until you make change to your build, you won't find any functions to Java to JNI/JNA to dynamically link to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said by technomage:

> JNA can load from DLLs that use C linkage. A C# class does not by
>   default support any kind of C linkage. C++ supports C linkage with the
>   extern "C" notation.

[This article](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Do-you-know-a-tool-to-automate-making-C-DLLs-exports-callable-from-native-code) shows a way to make C# DLLs methods callable like C-style DLL, unfortunately it's a quite complex.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 4):

This Nugget is super easy to use and works perfectly. https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports

You need Visual Studio 2012 (express).
Once installed, just add  `[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]` before any static function you want to export. That's it!

**Example:**

**C#**

```
[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
public static int YourFunction(string data)
{
     /*Your code here*/
     return 1;
}
```

**Java**

Add the import at the top:

```
   import com.sun.jna.Native;
```

Add the interface in your class. Its your C# function name preceded by the letter "I":

```
  public interface IYourFunction extends com.sun.jna.Library
    {
       public int YourFunction(String tStr);
    };
```

Call your DLL where you need it in your class:

```
IYourFunction iYourFunction = (IYourFunction )Native.loadLibrary("full or relative path to DLL withouth the .dll extention", IYourFunction.class);//call JNA
        System.out.println("Returned: " + IYourFunction.YourFunction("some parameter"));
```

Comment: Really? I'll try it :D

Comment: Tried this myself. Remarkably easy. Only catch is processor architecture, which must match between your project & unit test projects in VS, your default processor architecture setting in VS under Test | Test Settings | Default Processor Architecture, and the bitness of the interop environment that loads the .dll.