# Calling windows UWP API's from Java with JNA

Tags: java, uwp, java-native-interface, windows-runtime, jna

How can I call a windows UWP API from the JVM?
For example the [Windows.Security.Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault) API.
When attempting to use JNA none of the native library names I have tried will link, and I can't actually find a DLL that matches the name `Windows.Security.Credentials.dll` as described in the documentation.

Is what I want to do even possible, how can I link to and call UWP API's?

Comment: You might find the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474398/how-to-use-c-sharp-function-in-java-using-jna-lib) helpful.

Comment: I don't think it is really helpful. One answer says you can't do it and the other only works for functions where you have control over the source code.

Comment: @user2543253 I have actually made some limited progress with JNA, trying to figure out why im getting an error from `RoGetActivationFactory` at the moment.
https://gist.github.com/magJ/85c2d64afa09a39f44761ce5b3bceee5

Answer (score 1):

Update: I completely missed the mark on my first answer, was thinking JNI, not JNA, which looks a bit more like C# pInvoke. The code below is roughly what you'll need, but you'll need to reconstruct the v-tables for IInspectable and IPasswordVault. You can use the activation factory instead of activating the instance through RoActivateInstance, but then you'll need to reconstruct the interface for IActivationFactory as well. Otherwise the call suquence below is correct, if in the wrong language.

You can link and call against RoActivateInstance or RoGetActivationFactory and use the low-level COM-styl ABI interfaces defined the SDK in Windows.Security.Credentials.h. Same import lib as above.

eg:

```
IInspectable *pI {};
Windows::Security::Credentials::IPasswordVault pPV;
HRESULT hr = RoActivateInstance(L"Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault", &pI);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
  hr = pI->QueryInterface(__uuidof(Windows::Security::Credentials::IPasswordVault), (void**)&pPV);
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
  IVectorView<IPasswordCredential> *pPV{}; // namespaces omitted
  hr = pPV->RetrieveAll(&pPV);
}
```

Comment: You can actually do what the second example does directly from Java with JNA (wouldn't recommend that for JNA beginners, however)